# writing string array to file in c

Tags: c, file

```
int f = open("/tmp/vars.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH);

if (f == NULL)
{
    printf("Error opening file!\n");
    exit(1);
}
write(f, string_array, 100); //doesnt work
```

I've also tried

```
FILE *f = fopen(vars.txt, "wb") //and 'w"
fprintf(f, "array = %s ", string_array);
```

didn't print anything

I haven't used C in a long time. Can anyone help please.

Even if I replace `string_array` with just text.. `write(f, "test", 10)`.. it doesn't write anything to the file.

**solved** I was having a problem with buffers.. I fixed it.

Comment: What is `string_array`? What does "doesn't work" mean? You are writing to a file, it shouldn't print anything to the screen.

Comment: Please add the code where you create and initialise the `string_array`.

Comment: //doesnt work means the file is empty

Comment: even if i replace "string_array" with just text.. write(f, "test", 10).. it doesnt write anything to the file

Comment: Do you close the file? Please, provide a complete example.

Answer (score 1):

In the code you posted, [`open(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/open) creates (thanks to `O_CREAT` flag) a text file, but doesn't set the write permission to it correctly. Try replacing it with:

```
int f = open("/tmp/vars.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
```

In addition, when writing is done, you should [`close(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/close) the file descriptor:

```
if (close(f) < 0) {
    perror("close");
    exit(1);
}
```

---

Furthermore, [`open(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/open) doesn't return `NULL` on error. So you should check for `-1` instead.

Comment: int f = open("/tmp/vars.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);

    if (f == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening file!\n");
    }
    write(f, "test", 30);
    write(f, "test", 30);
    write(f, "test", 30);
    if(close(f) < 0){
             perror("close");
            exit(1)
    }

still won't work

Comment: @thisguy: I pointed out a possible issue, not **the only** issue in your code. Nobody can help you unless more information is provided.

Comment: after running: -rw-r--r--